# Electron app not spawning child process when moved to different folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

When a button is clicked in my app, a child process is spawned using the `fork()` function. This works as intended, even when bundled into an exe in my `dist` folder (via **electron-builder**). However, when I move the folder `win-unpacked` to another folder for testing, the child process is not spawned.

The `dist` folder structure is as shown:

```
dist
|-.icon-ico
|- win-unpacked
|- builder-debug.yaml
|- builder-effective-config.yaml
```

The `win-unpacked` is where all the main files are (such as app.asar, app.exe and such).

When it is in my main development folder such as this:

```
app
|-build
|-node_modules
|-dist
|-public
|-src
```

The child process is spawned, however, in the testing folder which just contains `dist`, the child process is not spawned.

To spawn the child process I have used:

```
child = fork(require("path").join(__dirname, "sts/states.js"));
```

In console, the `__dirname` is logged as `C:\Users\me\Documents\mainApp\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar\build`.

the `sts` folder is located in `build` folder.

I do not actually know what the reason is to why this is not working when I take `dist` out of my `app` folder and place it into another folder for testing.

Answer (score 0):

With some help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255723/electron-app-error-when-moving-build-folder), I managed to get some direction. I added:

```
"build": {
    "extraResources": "node_modules",
    "files": [
      "!node_modules"
    ]
}
```

to my `package.json` and now it is spawning the child process. The downside is that the file is now larger (1.45GB).